# The most fascinating site in the country is/are the men blowing trumpets

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

> A)The most fascinating site in the country **is** the men blowing trumpets.
>   B)The most fascinating site in the country **are** the men blowing trumpets.

Which among the two is correct?
Which form should the verb be used if we have a singular subject and a plural verb?

Comment: Single subject, single verb. The ... **sight** ... **is** ... - and use sight, not site (a site is a location), unless you mean the site **where** the men blow trumpets.

Comment: Do you mean "site" or do you mean "sight"... they are homophones but they don't mean the same things.

Answer (score 1):

Correct is

> A)The most fascinating site in the country **is** the men blowing trumpets.
>   B)The most fascinating site**s** in the country **are** the men blowing trumpets.

Also, "*site*" should be "*sight*" since you are probably talking about the *visual spectacle* and not the location.

> > A)The most fascinating **sight** in the country **is** the men blowing trumpets.

in which case *singular* "*sight*" is correct.